# Retrieving tail text from html

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

Python 2.7 using lxml

I have some annoyingly formed html that looks like this:

```
<td>
<b>"John"
</b>
<br>
"123 Main st.
"
<br>
"New York
"
<b>
"Sally"
</b>
<br>
"101 California St.
"
<br>
"San Francisco
"
</td>
```

So basically it's a single td with a ton of stuff in it. I'm trying to compile a list or dict of the names and their addresses.

So far what I've done is gotten a list of nodes with names using `tree.xpath('//td/b')`. So let's assume I'm currently on the `b` node for John.

I'm trying to get `whatever.xpath('string()')` for everything following the current node but preceding the next `b` node (Sally). I've tried a bunch of different xpath queries but can't seem to get this right. In particular, any time I use an `and` operator in an expression that has no `[]` brackets, it returns a bool rather than a list of all nodes meeting the conditions. Can anyone help out?

Comment: Since filtering for elements that comply with an expression is what brackets *do*, why would you want to not have them (assuming that your `and` is adding conditions to your expression, which is what it's for)? Could you show what you've tried, specifically including how you're trying to use `and`?

Comment: ...your current answers are fine insofar as they go, but they aren't likely to help someone who's here with the same question you give in the title (trying to apply multiple conditions to an XPath query); if you added more information, an answer to the titular question should be possible. If you aren't interested in doing so, by contrast, you might consider editing the question title to better reflect what you actually care about.

Comment: I would also recommend changing the title, perhaps to something like "Retrieving Tail Text from HTML", as that was at the heart of the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
from lxml import etree

p = etree.HTMLParser()
html = open(r'./test.html','r')
data = html.read()
tree = etree.fromstring(data, p)

my_dict = {}

for b in tree.iter('b'):
    br = b.getnext().tail.replace('\n', '')
    my_dict[b.text.replace('\n', '')] = br

print my_dict
```

This code prints:

```
{'"John"': '"123 Main st."', '"Sally"': '"101 California St."'}
```

(You may want to strip the quotation marks out!)

Rather than using xpath, you could use one of lxml's parsers in order to easily navigate the HTML.  The parser will turn the HTML document into an "etree", which you can navigate with provided methods.  The lxml module provides a method called `iter()` which allows you to pass in a tag name and receive all elements in the tree with that name.  In your case, if you use this to obtain all of the `<b>` elements, you can then manually navigate to the `<br>` element and retrieve its tail text, which contains the information you need. You can find information about this in the "Elements contain text" header of the [lxml.etree tutorial.](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html)

Comment: Somehow I never learned about `tail` for dealing with breaks but it's amazing! Thanks!

Comment: No prob, honestly just learned about it myself!  Since I work with XML every day at work, it was a good learning experience for me too.

Answer (score 0):

What not use getchildren function from view of each td. For example:

```
from lxml import html

s = """
<td>
<b>"John"
</b>
<br>
"123 Main st.
"
<br>
"New York
"
<b>
"Sally"
</b>
<br>
"101 California St.
"
<br>
"San Francisco
"
</td>
"""

records = []
cur_record = -1
cur_field = 1

FIELD_NAME = 0
FIELD_STREET = 1
FIELD_CITY = 2

doc = html.fromstring(s)
td = doc.xpath('//td')[0]
for child in td.getchildren():
    if child.tag == 'b':
        cur_record += 1
        record = dict()
        record['name'] = child.text.strip()
        records.append(record)
        cur_field = 1
    elif child.tag == 'br':
        if cur_field == FIELD_STREET:
            records[cur_record]['street'] = child.tail.strip()
            cur_field += 1
        elif cur_field == FIELD_CITY:
            records[cur_record]['city'] = child.tail.strip()
```

And the results are:

```
records = [
           {'city': '"New York\n"', 'name': '"John"\n', 'street': '"123 Main st.\n"'},
           {'city': '"San Francisco\n"', 'name': '\n"Sally"\n', 'street': '"101 California St.\n"'}
          ]
```

Note you should use `tag.tail` if you want to get text of some non-close html tag, e.g., `<br>`.

Hope this would be helpful.